# ebay api (EPN) Query to pull classified items and auction items (auction items with 1 bid minimum)

Tags: php, ebay-api

This may be too localized. But using the EPN (ebay) api, I am trying to pull only auction items with a minimum bid of 1 and then all classified items.

This is what I have as my item filters:

```
&itemFilter(0).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(0).value=10

&itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value=10000000000000000

&itemFilter(2).name=ListingType&itemFilter(2).value(0)=Auction

&itemFilter(2).value(1)=Classified

&itemFilter(3).name=MinBids&itemFilter(3).value=1
```

From what I can work out, it appears that when I add:

```
&itemFilter(3).name=MinBids&itemFilter(3).value=1
```

It overrides the command to list items in classified. So it just shows auction items with minimum bid of 1.

Can I achieve what I want at all?